# Cucumber with playwright does not recognize .TS files in ES2022 module configuration

Tags: angular, playwright, cucumberjs

I'm trying to implement cucumber with playwright tests in that way:

- has one cucumber.cjs file which will be my runner
- has tests > acceptance > features > {here all .features files}
- has tests > step_definitions > here all .steps.ts files with custom-world.ts and common hooks.ts files.

Here is instruction for reference https://www.genui.com/resources/getting-started-with-bdd-using-cucumber-io

common-hooks.ts

```
import { ICustomWorld } from "./custom-world";
import {
    ChromiumBrowser,
    chromium
} from '@playwright/test'
import { After, AfterAll, Before, BeforeAll } from '@cucumber/cucumber'
let browser: ChromiumBrowser

BeforeAll(async function() {
    browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false, channel: "chrome" })
  });
  
Before(async function(this: ICustomWorld) {
  this.context = await browser.newContext()
  this.page = await this.context.newPage()
});

After(async function(this: ICustomWorld) {
  await this.page?.close()
  await this.context?.close()
});
  
AfterAll(async function() {
  await browser.close()
});
```

custom-world.ts

```
import { IWorldOptions, World, setWorldConstructor } from '@cucumber/cucumber'
import { BrowserContext, Page } from '@playwright/test'

export interface ICustomWorld extends World {
    context?: BrowserContext
    page?: Page
}

export class CustomWorld extends World implements ICustomWorld {
    constructor(options: IWorldOptions) {
        super(options)
    }
}

setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)
```

simple_counter.steps.ts

```
import { Given, When, Then } from '@cucumber/cucumber'
import { expect } from '@playwright/test'
import { ICustomWorld } from './custom-world'

Given('User visits homepage', async function (this: ICustomWorld) {
    const page = this.page!
    await page.goto('localhost:3000')
})

When('User clicks the + button', async function (this: ICustomWorld) {
    const page = this.page!
    const plusButton = await page.locator('[data-testid="increase"]')
    await expect(plusButton).toBeVisible()
    await plusButton.click()
})

Then('User sees the counter get increased', async function (this: ICustomWorld) {
    const page = this.page!
    const counterText = await page.locator('[data-testid="counter-text"]')
    await expect(counterText).toHaveText('Count: 1')
  })
```

cucumber.cjs

```
const config = {
    paths: ['tests/acceptance/features/**/*.feature'],
    require: ['tests/acceptance/step_definitions/**/*.ts'],
    requireModule: ['ts-node/register'],
    format: [
      'summary',
      'progress-bar',
    ],
    formatOptions: { snippetInterface: 'async-await' },
    publishQuiet: true,
  };

module.exports = {
   default: config
 }
```

I don't want to change module and target in my tsconfig file. I use this:

```
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
```

I got below error message

`Cucumber expected a CommonJS module at 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\my-application\tests\acceptance\step_definitions\common-hooks.ts' but found an ES module. Either change the file to CommonJS syntax or use the --import directive instead of --require.`

and full message

`Original error message: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\User\source\repos\myApp\tests\acceptance\step_definitions\common-hooks.ts require() of ES modules is not supported. require() of C:\Users\User\source\repos\myApp\tests\acceptance\step_definitions\common-hooks.ts from C:\Users\User\source\repos\myApp\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\try_require.js is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\User\source\repos\myApp\package.json.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel like I fully understand what worked for me, but here are the actions:

- Rename `require` in `cucumber.cjs` to `import`.
- Remove `requireModule` from there.
- Change the `test` script in `package.json` from `cucumber-js test` to `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' cucumber-js`.

Also, the `"type"` should be `"module"` in `package.json`.

Comment: I lost a bunch of time on this as well and your answer was very helpful then I decided to read more carefully their transpiling documentation regarding ESM loaders and found the answer here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/esm.md#transpiling